# Count if value is lower than 80 and equal or bigger than 0 but not empty

Tags: if-statement, conditional-statements, range, google-sheets-formula, countif

I'm trying to countif some values but not the empty ones this is my formula and this is the data that I try to count:

```
=COUNTIF(B2:B15,"<0.8, >=0")
```

But this formula counts the empty one too, I would like to have only one like in the image in colum b should be count only 2 but it count 13.

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try

```
=COUNTIFS(B2:B15,"<0.8",B2:B15,">0")
```

[COUNTIFS](https://support.google.com/docs/answer/3256550)

or

```
=SUMPRODUCT((B2:B15<0.8)*(B2:B15>0))
```

[SUMRPODUCT](https://support.google.com/docs/answer/3094294)